# SDK Implementation lib/inc/dll

Tags: c++, dll, sdk

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio and an SDK to develop an app. The SDK includes the files listed above. I'm coding in C++. I'm not sure what I need to include to be able to use the SDK.

I did the things below and tried building a simple hello world app but I keep getting the error `LNK2019: unresolved external symbol_WinMain@16 referenced in function __tmainCRTStartup`

What I've Done:

1)Right Click-Properties-Linker-Additional Library Directories-Changed path to where I have the lib folder on my computer.

2)Same but added the Inc folder that came with the SDK to C/C++ Additional Include Directories.

By doing the above I assume I am linking the lib and .h files to the project that came with the SDK. The SDK also came with .dll files which I have done nothing with. You can use a few different languages with the SDK so I'm not sure what I need to use and not use.

However, the header files are not showing up under external dependencies.

I guess I should note that I have tried to run it a couple times before this and am not sure if that could be causing an issue building it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're seeing has nothing to do with header files or source code.  The error is due to you not choosing the correct Visual Studio project.

If you are writing a console program, and you defined a `main()` function as the entry point, then you should be choosing a `Win32 Console Application` project from Visual Studio.

The error stems from the program looking for the `WinMain` function, and that function exists when you choose a `Win32 Project`.  Usually these projects are for building GUI-based Win32 apps.

Comment: When I choose new project I'm choosing Win32 App. Would it matter if I made it a Windows App instead of console app? I'm also selecting empty project and disabled SDL. Trying to make a new project and starting over.Thanks.

Comment: Then your entry point must be `WinMain`, not `main()` if you choose `Win32 Application`.  If all you want to do is the simplest thing, i.e. write a simple console app that tests out the SDK function, I highly suggest you just choose `Win32 Console` as the project and stick with `main()` as the entry point.

Comment: Did that and it's working. The header files from the SDK aren't showing up but that's a different issue. I can at least compile helloworld. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user4342836 - If the answer solves the issue, please vote that this is the solution.  Thanks.